# How to get only specific strings or records from Twitter

Tags: r, api, twitter, stream

```
names(st)<-c("id_str", "created_at", "text", "location")

parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("climate change"), timeout=10, oauth=twitCred))$st

# [1]   6113    214   3649   1444   4483    270   8022  41946 494038   8925   3454   5249  20517  14790  14276  15316 583259   4254   3962   6635  52878   3669   2230   6186   9348 583267
#[27]  46894  17360  18038   3764
```

I do not want to see the numbers like these. I want to see actual tweets. For example

```
id_str             created_at                    text    location
   xxx    Mon Jun 01 16:52:33  ABCDEFG climate change          UK
  xxx1    Mon Jun 01 16:52:33   XYZCDF climate change   Australia
  xxxB    Mon Jun 01 16:52:34   climate change XYZCDF         USA
```

Comment: Maybe `st` is the wrong attribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please review the examples at the bottom of `?parseTweets` before posting a question.

the object `st` in this line

```
names(st)<-c("id_str", "created_at", "text", "location")
```

has nothing to do with the `st` at the end of your `parseTweets` call.  you are using the `$` operator and so it completes the string by searching for `$statuses_count` which also begins with `st`

remove the `$st` at the end of your parseTweets command and you will see that you actually want the `$text` column instead.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the results. In case, anyone else stumbles to the same problem. Following is the code. parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("lebron"), timeout=10, oauth=my_oauth))[,c("text","created_at")]